# How to get gamecenter app friends in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center

How to get list of gamecenter friends who are playing my game in iphone.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`-[GKLocalPlayer loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009587).  For example (untested code):

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler:
    ^(NSArray *friends, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            // Handle error
        }
        else
        {
            // friends is an array of player identifiers of the user's friends
            // Now would be a good time to copy or retain it.
        }
    } ];
```

Comment: it will fetch also those friends who are not using my app:(